# Misalignment of triangles drawn with tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wrote this function that draw a grid of triangles:

```
def create_triangles(side_length):
    result = []
    half_width = int(side_length / 2)
    # height = int(side_length * math.sqrt(3) / 2)
    height = side_length
    max_width = 15 * side_length
    max_height = 10 * height

    for i in range(0, max_height, height):
        if (i / height) % 2 == 0:
            for j in range(0, max_width-half_width, half_width):
                if j % side_length == 0:
                    triangle = (i-height/2, j-half_width, i+height/2, j, i-height/2, j+half_width)
                else:
                    triangle = (i-height/2, j, i+height/2, j+half_width, i+height/2, j-half_width)

                result.append(triangle)
        else:
            for j in range(half_width, max_width, half_width):
                if j % side_length == 0:
                    triangle = (i-height/2, j-2*half_width, i+height/2, j-half_width+2, i-height/2, j)
                else:
                    triangle = (i-height/2, j-half_width, i+height/2, j, i+height/2, j-2*half_width)

                result.append(triangle)

    return result
```

The current output is this:

[image: screenshot of current output]

As you can see some triangles are misaligned but I don't understand why.

Comment: do you use Python 2 or 3 ? in Python 2 dividing two integers you get integer instead of float  - `1/2` gives `0` instead of `0.5`.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: so you have float values when you divide - but floats still can give incorrect result -ie. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` gives `False`

Comment: The picture i posted has been created calling the function with `side_length = 40`

Comment: with float always can be problem - you can use `print()` to see values in variables in different places. Maybe this help you to find problem.

Comment: I tried to replace all `/` with `//` to force integer division, in this case i should be handling only integers, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: if you use // to get integer values then you may get even worst result. You may have to round() it instead of using // or `int()` (`int()` will round down to the nearest integer but you may have to round up).

Comment: yea, you are right, but what sound strange to me is that not all triagles are drawn badly. Inside the for loop, the outer if draws the odd colums and the else draws the even columns, the two inner if draw the triangles that are arrows pointing to the right and the else the left ones. It seems to me that the problematic triangles are the ones in the even columns pointing to the right.

Edit:
if i comment that line all other triangle are drawn well and this should confirm my theory

Comment: you may calculate the same position in different way and it can give little different result. Example `0.3 - 0.1 == 0.1 + 0.1` also gives `False` but it seems that there is `0.2 == 0.2`

Comment: How are you drawing the triangles? There are no tkinter calls shown in the code in you question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, floating points give you incorrect results; You want to make sure that the shared points representing the vertices of two adjacent triangles are concurrent. A simple approach is to reduce the points coordinates to ints, and organize the calculations so errors do not add up.

In the following examples, the misalignment is corrected, every triangle on the canvas is represented by a polygon, and individually drawn; each triangle can therefore be referenced when moused over, or addressed via an index, or a mapping (not implemented).

```
import tkinter as tk
import math


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500


class Point:
    """convenience for point arithmetic
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y


def tile_with_triangles(canvas, side_length=50):
    """tiles the entire surface of the canvas with triangular polygons
    """
    triangle_height = int(side_length * math.sqrt(3) / 2)
    half_side = side_length // 2
    p0 = Point(0, 0)
    p1 = Point(0, side_length)
    p2 = Point(triangle_height, half_side)

    for idx, x in enumerate(range(-triangle_height, WIDTH+1, triangle_height)):
        for y in range(-side_length, HEIGHT+1, side_length):
            y += half_side * (idx%2 + 1)
            offset = Point(x, y)
            pa, pb, pc = p0 + offset, p1 + offset,p2 + offset
            canvas.create_polygon(*pa, *pb, *pc, outline='black', fill='', activefill='red')

    p2 = Point(-triangle_height, half_side)  # flip the model triangle

    for idx, x in enumerate(range(-triangle_height, WIDTH+triangle_height+1, triangle_height)):
        for y in range(-side_length, HEIGHT+1, side_length):
            y += half_side * (idx%2 + 1)
            offset = Point(x, y)
            pa, pb, pc = p0 + offset, p1 + offset,p2 + offset
            canvas.create_polygon(*pa, *pb, *pc, outline='black', fill='', activefill='blue')


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='cyan')
canvas.pack()

tile_with_triangles(canvas) #, side_length=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I added an active fill property that will change the colors of each triangle when you mouse over.

[image]
[image]